# RegEx split sentence in words and symbols with exceptions

Tags: python, regex

I have made this piece of code:

```
import re

sentence = "Hello, StackOverflow!" # Sample input
words = re.findall(r"\w+|[^\w\s]", sentence, re.UNICODE)
print(words)
```

Which works surprisingly well. This is the sample output `['Hello', ',', 'StackOverflow', '!']`.

The important part about this RegEx is the ability to split words from symbols correctly even when there is a space (ex. 'Hello World!' and 'Hello World !' get split in the same way).

Now, I need to blacklist a combination of these symbols, particulary `f/xxxx` (xxxx is a placeholder, there could be anything in there).

Example:

> "This is a sentence containing: f/thiscanbeanything" should be split into `['This','is','a','sentence','containing',':','f/thiscanbeanything']`

How can I achieve this? (word order is very important!)

Comment: what do you mean by blacklist ? can you show sample input and expected blacklisted output?

Comment: By blacklist I mean 'exclude this specific string from being split'. The example I made is exactly what I want.

Comment: why don't you first remove all punctuations and then try regex ?

Comment: Punctuation is crucial for my code.

Comment: What do you want to happen with `f/!hello!` and `f/hello!`

Comment: @A.Dandelion then remove the punctuation after split ?

Comment: Try `\b(?:f\/\w+|\w+)\b|\S`. Live demo https://regex101.com/r/O7Pdgl/1

Comment: I know for a fact that `f/!hello` will not appear. `f/hello!` should be split into `['f/hello','!']`.

Comment: @revo this is working correctly, although `_w_` does not get split.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

How about:

```
f\/\w+|\w+|[^\w\s]
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/Va3Llp/1

Comment: Why the downvote here, can I have some feedback so I can fix the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Change your regex to `r"f/\w+|\w+|[^\w\s]"` (as the first alternative
I added `f/\w+`). In Python you don't even need to escape the `/` char
(as you would have to in other host languages).

It is important that the added fragment is the first alternative.
Otherwise e.g. `\w+` alternative would have "won" and matched `f` only.

Note: I assumed that your `thiscanbeanything` is a sequence of word
chars. If this is not the case (e.g. a sequence of non-space chars),
change this alternative accordingly.